# Server sided editing of office (word,excel,powerpoint) document properties

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I have a office integration plugin project written in C# .NET 4.
The plugin allow to download and edit (or create new documents) in Word, Excel, and Powerpoint and finally save them in our intranet.

To identify a document to the record inside the database i save the record guid as property "guid" in the office document file. This works fine as long I create and edit all files using office with the plugin.

But if I upload any office document over a web form and store it this document might not have a guid property. But the record in the database has one. So the solution is to add the guid property server sided.

I wrote a command line tool for RoR and made a COM+ object for scripting where I can add/modify those properties. Only problem is, that I need office (Word, Excel, Powerpoint) installed on the server.
, because we have the need of support version 2003,2007,2010.

I checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739835%28v=office.12%29.aspx already, but this won't work with version 2003.

---

So here is the question :): Does anyone know a solution where I don't need to install office on the server or do I have to live with it? Third party (even commercial if good ones) are welcomed as well if they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used [aspose.com/](http://www.aspose.com/) components in the past to edit office documents on the server.

Note: I am not related to the company.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the trial beside the open xml sdk as well.